# Erro: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Quando eu tento conectar à minha base de dados por php dá este erro:
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Uma tentativa de liga��o falhou porque o componente ligado n�o respondeu corretamente ap�s um per�odo de tempo, ou a liga��o estabelecida falhou porque o anfitri�o ligado n�o respondeu. in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
Connection failed: Uma tentativa de liga��o falhou porque o componente ligado n�o respondeu corretamente ap�s um per�odo de tempo, ou a liga��o estabelecida falhou porque o anfitri�o ligado n�o respondeu.

como posso proceder?

```
<?php
        $servername = "*****";
        $username = "****";
        $password = "*****";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>
```

A base de dados não está no computador mas sim na rede da minha empresa

Answer (score 0):

Este erro acontece porque você não deve estar conseguindo acessar o servidor.

A primeira coisa é fazer um teste de `telnet`

No *prompt* do DOS digite

```
telnet $servername 3306
```

Se você estiver usando para o `$servername` o nome do servidor e não o IP (*hostname*) talvez você precise configurar o `etc/hosts` do Windows ou então usar o IP do servidor pra se conectar

Primeiro faça o teste do `telnet` e posta a resposta no tópico